# Hide controls(pause, forward button etc) of videView Media controller when backButton pressed in Android 9

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-9.0-pie, onbackpressed, mediacontroller

I'm using **videoView** to play video on app, **MediaController** is used to play video. In **Android 9** when controls are showing in bottom of playing video then back button of Android doesn't call. I'm Using fragment. When i press back button then override `onBackPressed()` doesn't call but when after few seconds video controls hides itself then `onBackPressed()` calls by pressing back button.

It's pertinent of mention here that such problem doesn't happens in **Android 5**.

Comment: Tried using INVISIBILITY ? Set it to invisible when backbutton pressed

Comment: backbutton pressing doesn't detect by code

Comment: Please post your code